# Gatsby: How can I pass multiple context IDs to a single query?

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby, wp-graphql

I'm trying to get data from two separate objects in a single query using their WordPress IDs, but I'm getting `GraphQLError: The ID input is invalid. Make sure you set the proper idType for your input.` Using the GraphQL IDE in WordPress it fetches all the data as expected, but I get that error in my code. If I set the idType to a string, for example, I get `Variable "$editorId" of type "String!" used in position expecting type "ID!".`

gatsby-node.js > createPages function:

```
// Video Detail pages
  const {
    data: {
      cartel: { videoDetailPages },
    },
  } = await graphql(`
    query {
      cartel {
        videoDetailPages(first: 300) {
          nodes {
            id
            slug
            videoDetail {
              editor
              editorId
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  const videoDetailTemplate = path.resolve(`./src/templates/videoDetail.js`);

  videoDetailPages.nodes.forEach(page => {
    const editorSlug = page.videoDetail.editor.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase();
    const { editorId } = page.videoDetail;

    createPage({
      // will be the url for the page
      path: `${editorSlug}/${page.slug}`,
      // specify the component template of your choice
      component: slash(videoDetailTemplate),
      // In the ^template's GraphQL query, 'id' will be available
      // as a GraphQL variable to query for this page's data.
      context: {
        id: page.id,
        editorId,
      },
    });
  });
```

page template query:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($id: ID!, $editorId: ID!) {
    cartel {
      videoDetailPage(id: $id) {
        videoDetail {
          client
          director
          duration
          editor
          productionCompany
          videoStill {
            altText
            sourceUrl
          }
          videoUrl
          title
        }
      }
    }
    cartel {
      editorDetailPage(id: $editorId) {
        editorDetail {
          editorVideos {
            pagePath
            image {
              altText
              sourceUrl
              title
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

gatsby-info:

```
  System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.7
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-8950HK CPU @ 2.90GHz
    Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 10.23.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.23.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.4 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.8 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.23.0/bin/npm
  Languages:
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 91.0.4472.77
    Firefox: 87.0
    Safari: 14.1
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^2.24.36 => 2.32.13 
    gatsby-image: ^2.4.14 => 2.11.0 
    gatsby-plugin-accessibilityjs: ^1.0.3 => 1.0.3 
    gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager: ^2.3.11 => 2.11.0 
    gatsby-plugin-manifest: ^2.4.22 => 2.12.1 
    gatsby-plugin-offline: ^2.2.7 => 2.2.10 
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^3.3.10 => 3.10.0 
    gatsby-plugin-remove-trailing-slashes: ^2.3.11 => 2.10.0 
    gatsby-plugin-sass: ^2.3.12 => 2.8.0 
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^2.6.25 => 2.14.4 
    gatsby-plugin-sitemap: ^2.4.11 => 2.12.0 
    gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader: ^1.0.4 => 1.0.4 
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^2.3.24 => 2.11.1 
    gatsby-source-graphql: ^3.4.0 => 3.4.0 
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^2.5.12 => 2.12.1
```

I'm not having any luck finding what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it sorted out. Needed to use a where query on the list of editorDetailPages. Thanks very much to Ferran Buireu for guiding me in the right direction.

gatsby-node.js > createPages function:

```
// Video Detail pages
  const {
    data: {
      cartel: { videoDetailPages },
    },
  } = await graphql(`
    query {
      cartel {
        videoDetailPages(first: 300) {
          nodes {
            id
            slug
            videoDetail {
              editor
              editorId
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  const videoDetailTemplate = path.resolve(`./src/templates/videoDetail.js`);

  videoDetailPages.nodes.forEach(page => {
    const editorSlug = page.videoDetail.editor.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase();
    const { editorId } = page.videoDetail;

    createPage({
      // will be the url for the page
      path: `${editorSlug}/${page.slug}`,
      // specify the component template of your choice
      component: slash(videoDetailTemplate),
      // In the ^template's GraphQL query, 'id' will be available
      // as a GraphQL variable to query for this page's data.
      context: {
        id: page.id,
        editorId: parseInt(editorId, 10),
      },
    });
  });
```

page template query:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($id: ID!, $editorId: Int!) {
    cartel {
      videoDetailPage(id: $id) {
        videoDetail {
          client
          director
          duration
          editor
          productionCompany
          videoStill {
            altText
            sourceUrl
          }
          videoUrl
          title
        }
      }
    }
    cartel {
      editorDetailPages(where: { id: $editorId }) {
        nodes {
          editorDetail {
            editorVideos {
              pagePath
              image {
                altText
                sourceUrl
                title
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `gatsby-node.js` looks perfect. Your issue is caused by the types of the data context you are sending to the template (`videoDetailTemplate`). You are telling to GraphQL that both `id` and `editorId` are `ID` types while I guess they should be strings.

I guess changing this line:

```
  query($id: ID!, $editorId: ID!) {
```

To this should do the trick:

```
  query($id: String!, $editorId: String!) {
```

As you can see from [GraphQL types definition docs](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#scalar-types):

> The `ID` scalar type represents a unique identifier, often used to
> refetch an object or as the key for a cache. The ID type is serialized
> in the same way as a String; however, defining it as an `ID` signifies
> that it is not intended to be human‐readable.

*Note: spot the difference between String an ID types ("defining it as an `ID` signifies that it is not intended to be human‐readable")*

You should be able to configure the types for each field in the plugin's setup:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-graphql",
      options: {
        // Remote schema query type. This is an arbitrary name.
        typeName: "WPGraphQL",
        // Field name under which it will be available. Used in your Gatsby query. This is also an arbitrary name.
        fieldName: "wpcontent",
        // GraphQL endpoint, relative to your WordPress home URL.
        url: "https://example.com/blog/graphql",
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Additionally, you should be able to force the types using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), etc, methods at the time you send it through context.

Then use the `where` filter as the documentation suggests:

```
editorDetailPage(where: { id: $editorId})

videoDetailPage (where: { id: $id})
```

Can you provide more details about your implementation (plugins, configurations, versions, etc)? It seems to be a bug:

### Resources:

- Guides

  - https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/glossary/wpgraphql/
  - https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-graphql/
- Issues

  - https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql/issues/1524
  - https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql/issues/532
  - https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql/issues/109
  - https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql/issues/997

Comment: Doing that I get `Variable "$id" of type "String!" used in position expecting type "ID!".` and `Variable "$editorId" of type "String!" used in position expecting type "ID!".`.

Comment: Are you setting somewhere the types? Have you tried removing the exclamation mark  (`!`) that means that the field is non-nullable

Comment: No. The GraphiQL IDE treats it like a string, but GQL expects an ID.
```
query MyQuery {
  videoDetailPage(id: "515", idType: DATABASE_ID) {
    videoDetail {
      client
      director
      duration
      editor
      editorId
      productionCompany
      title
      videoStill {
        altText
        sourceUrl
      }
      videoUrl
    }
  }
  editorDetailPage(id: "194", idType: DATABASE_ID) {
    editorDetail {
      editorVideos {
        pagePath
        image {
          altText
          sourceUrl
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It should yes, the idea is to avoid spam in the comment sections and try different stuff to fix your issue. If you try removing the non-nullable field and the issue disappears we would detect the cause so we can try to fix it. Now we're blind. That's why I ask trying to set it as nullable.

Comment: It's expecting a non-nullible variable. `Variable "$editorId" of type "ID" used in position expecting type "ID!".` and `Variable "$editorId" of type "String" used in position expecting type "ID!".`

I've added the contents of `gatsby info` to the original post.

Comment: What about gatsby-source-graphql set up... where precisely the types are defined?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233264/discussion-between-mikeriley131-and-ferran-buireu).